engine.io has no exported member named 'ServerAttachOptions'
node_modules/@types/socket.io/index.d.ts:458:44 - error TS2724: '"/var/www/*****/node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io"' has no exported member named 'ServerAttachOptions'. Did you mean 'AttachOptions'?

458     interface ServerOptions extends engine.ServerAttachOptions {

I am getting this error after updating my package.json
Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "*****",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.4.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.4.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.4.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^10.4.1",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^10.4.1",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.8",
    "@types/redis": "^2.8.14",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "minimatch": "^10.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.4.5",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.1.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.4.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.1.1",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "jest": "^29.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}

I tried looking into this file node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.d.ts, but cannot find the relevant code with ServerAttachOptions
Which version of engine.io should i be up/downgrading ?
